# want to copy a specic text from other web in PHP

Tags: php

**Ltes say i want to copy a text from site ( http:// www.example.com/ex )**

when i open http:/ /www.example.com/ex it shows this data [click here](http://pastebin.com/bEKZHuRN)

i want to copy every text after MrsId which is in between the double quotes(means i want to copy MN4D / CN4D / MK4D / MO4D all othese four codes from example.com/ex  and these codes changes daily )

and sotre in a varible eg ( $a= 'MN4D', $b='CN4D' ,$c='MK4D'  ,$d='MO4D' )

then want to use it as

$first = 'http:// www.example.com/?code=';
 
 $url = "{$first}{$a}";
 
 $urll = "{$firsts}{$b}";
 
 $urlll = "{$firsts}{$c}";
 
 $urlllll = "{$firsts}{$d}";

$result = file_get_contents($url);
 
$results = file_get_contents($urll);
 
$resultss = file_get_contents($urlll);
 
$resultsss = file_get_contents($urllll);

echo $result;
 
echo $results;
 
echo $resultss;
 
echo $resultsss;

I am serching for this code from 1 month but did't get success yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code for your needs:

```
<?php
$json = '{"Amrlist":[{"Amcd":"mr-pub-4925511/1986","MrsId":"MN4D","BiclMine":"90","ImagePath":"http://my.example.com/myex/myex.jpg"},{"Amcd":"mr-pub-4925511/1986","MrsId":"CN4D","BiclMine":"90","ImagePath":"http://my.example.com/myex/myex.jpg"},{"Amcd":"mr-pub-4925511/1986","MrsId":"MK4D","BiclMine":"90","ImagePath":"http://my.example.com/myex/myex.jpg"},{"Amcd":"mr-pub-4925511/1986","MrsId":"MO4D","BiclMine":"90","ImagePath":"http://my.example.com/myex/myex.jpg"}]}';

$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
//var_dump($decoded);
$url = 'http://www.example.com/?code=';
foreach($decoded{'Amrlist'} as $Amrlist) {
  //print_r($Amrlist);
  print $url.$Amrlist['MrsId']."\n";
  //print file_get_contents($url.$Amrlist['MrsId']);
}
/**/
?>
```

Comment: **Thank you very much** :)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see - data has json format. So you can use json_decode to access needed fields